# Vue.js: v-model working only for the first select option

Tags: php, laravel-5, vue.js, vue-resource

I want to filter data from the database using `vue.js` In the blade file I have the following:

```
<div class="row" id="filterUnits">
    @{{message}}
    {!! Form::open() !!}

    <div class="large-3 columns">
        {!! Form::select('block', getBlocks($site),null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'All blocks', 'v-model'=>'block', 'v-on:change'=>'getUnits()']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        {!! Form::text('name', null,['class'=>'form-control', 'placeHolder'=>'Enter unit name']) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        {!! Form::select('floor', getSiteFloors($site),null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'All Floors', 'v-model'=>'floor', 'v-on:change'=>'getUnits()' ]) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        {!! Form::select('bedroom', getSiteBedrooms($site),null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'All Bedrooms', 'v-model'=>'bedroom', 'v-on:change'=>'getUnits()' ]) !!}
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 columns">
        {!! Form::select('status', getUnitStatus(),null, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'All Status', 'v-model'=>'status', 'v-on:change'=>'getUnits()' ]) !!}
    </div>

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

In my app.js :

```
    new Vue({
    el: '#filterUnits',
    data: {
        message: "Hey there Vue!",
        units: this.units
    },
    methods: {
        getUnits: function (unit) {
            this.$http.post('/admin/units').then(function (response) {
                console.log(response.data);
                this.units = response.data;
            }, function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

In the backend I receive the request data and perform filters, and that code is fine. When I check the request data that the function being called by the route above receives it is only the first input `{block: "1"}` even if I have selected the rest. If I don't select a `block` at all and select lets say `floor` the request received is an empty array.

I tried passing the input like this:

`this.$http.post('/admin/units', {block: this.block,floor: this.floor,bedroom: this.bedroom,status: this.status}).then(function (response)...`

but it doesn't help.

Comment: first comment, but not directly related - stop using forms. You don't need it when you are sending data with Vue.>

Comment: How will the user select the options to filter without forms?

Comment: Second is that: why you have `unit` argument in function when you never use it in request and you never pass it to function ?
Also, data: { units: this.units } is really strange and I don't see the point of using that. 
How you can say that in back end you receive data when you are not passing anything in the request ?

Comment: You can use inputs of course, but you don't have to wrap them with form. Sometimes it makes life easier.

Comment: I tried passing the inputs but it still doesn't work and the first input works even without passing it.

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking, but I can't see anything getting passed to your route, so each request will be to `/admin/units` with no request data, so you will get the same response each time.

Comment: @craig_h I did pass the data but it still doesn't work

Comment: Turns out my code is correct, my js files were not compiling and hence no change I made worked. Now those are 3 hours of my life I cannot get back.

Comment: I think your promise might benefit from a lexical this: `this.$http.post('/admin/units').then( (response) => {`

Comment: @darryn.ten using that gives me errors I am not sure if its the IDE am using that causes it. I am using PhpStorm.